# JSON deserializing nested response

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core

I'm having a novice problem deserializing a response from an API (.NET6, using System.Text.Json).
I get the response successfully using this:

```
    var itemresponse = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<JSON_Item>();
```

I get all nested values as expected in "itemresponse", fully visible in the VS debugger.
Now I wish to loop through the response and pull out relevant values - seems simple and straightforward...

### First issue:

I can pull out values from first level like this:

```
string test1 = itemresponse.product.title;
```

However, I cannot get a nested value from the Variant, like this:

```
string test2 = itemresponse.product.variants.sku;
```

All properties in "variants" are unknown, and I can not "dot" them in Visual Studio.

### Second issue:

I'm trying to loop through all values in the response using this:

```
foreach (var w in itemresponse.product)
{
    string test = w.vendor;         // Works
    string test2 = w.variants.sku;  // sku not recognizable
}
```

I'm aware that my "itemresponse" is not a list, but I would expect to be able to loop through the object anyhow.
Beeep.. Not possible. I'm getting this:
"foreach cannot operate on variables of type "Product" because "Product" does not contain a public instance or extension definition for "GetEnumerator".

Ok, I make a few changes:

```
var itemresponse = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<JSON_Item>>();
foreach (var w in itemresponse)
{
    string test = w.product.vendor;     // Works
    string test2 = w.product.variants.sku;  // sku still not recognizable
}
```

Trying to run, I get this:
JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Models.JSON_Item]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.

I'm stuck, and I don't know how to get nested values from "variants".
Kindly asking for help using "Best practice".

Thanks a lot in advance.

René

Below are the classes i use:

```
public class JSON_Item
{
    public Product product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public long? id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string body_html { get; set; }
    public string vendor { get; set; }
    public List<Variant> variants { get; set; }
}

public class Variant
{
    public long? id { get; set; }
    public long? product_id { get; set; }
    public string? title { get; set; }
    public string? price { get; set; }
    public string? sku { get; set; }
}
```

Example of response JSON:

```
{
   "product":{
      "id":6912905806009,
      "title":"This is the title",
      "body_html":"Description here...",
      "vendor":"Cronus Inc.",
      "variants":[
         {
            "id":40775169605817,
            "product_id":6912905806009,
            "title":"Variant 1",
            "price":"899.00",
            "sku":"5710698076083"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

EDIT: Will something like nested foreach loops be durable?

```
foreach (var q in itemresponse.product)
{
    string title = q.product.title;

    foreach (var w in itemresponse.product.variants)
    {
        string test = w.sku;
    }
}
```

If so, how do I then connect the loops so I make sure variants would be linked to the correct product looping through my JSON object?

I wonder what the "best practice" solution is to this? Guess this is a very common demand for extracting values from nested JSON objects?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the JSON string that you're getting in the response? You cannot iterate over objects, objects are not lists, it's unclear from what you posted as to whether itemresponse is a list of JSON_Item or just a single JSON_Item. Both your first and second issues appear to result from you treating product.variants as an object when it is actually a list. The list does not have the property SKU, but you could iterate over each variant in the product to get all of the skus. Or you could use some index (product.variant[0].sku).

Comment: Hi Emagers. Thanks a lot for your reply. I have now added example of response JSON.

Comment: *"I would expect to be able to loop through the object anyhow"* why would you expect that? You can't iterate something that isn't a list, there is only one of it. So you don't need to nest your `foreach`. But if you did have a root list of products, you would do `foreach (var w in q.variants)` in the inner foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first (and second issue, but more on that later), you cannot access SKU directly on the list of variants. In your example:

```
string test1 = itemresponse.product.title;
```

Works because title is a property of the product object.

```
string test2 = itemresponse.product.variants.sku;
```

Does not work because the variants list does not have a SKU property. You would need to access a specific variant object in the variants list to get the SKU. For instance, you could do the following:

```
foreach (var variant in itemresponse.product.variants) {
    Console.WriteLine(variant.sku);
}
```

For the second issue, in your examples you are treating an object (both itemresponse and product) as lists and trying to foreach over them. This is not valid. You can only foreach over an iterable data structure such as a list or an array. If you remove the foreach from those code snippets then you're left with the same issue as you had the first time, where you are trying to access a property of a variant object from a list of variants, which is also invalid.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution gives me indeed access to the SKU from the variant. Please see the last lines I just added to my question regarding nested foreach loops and connecting them correctly.

Comment: The outer loop: foreach(var q in itemresponse.product) is uneccessary, there is only every one product and nothing to loop over. From the way I understand the JSON you provided, every SKU in all the variants in the list belongs to that product. Understanding how you plan to use the product title along with the skus might help better answer your question, but at this point you have both pieces of data and their association

Comment: Ah yeah, of course. There is always only 1 product, so only 1 foreach loop will be nessesary to get variants. That solves my problems for now.

However, if there were multiple products, how would I then get the SKU's?

Comment: If there were multiple products, then it would be like what you have with nested for loops. That's where it would be helpful to know how you intend to use it, presumably you would want to perform some action with the title and SKU(s) in either the nested or outer for loop depending on the scenario.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your great advise. I really appreciate it.